# How can Irfanview (1st choice) or GIMP (2nd choice) make pictures much less yellow?

Tags: photo-editing

How do I remove this yellow tint from pictures?  My bathroom light is pure white, there should not be this yellow!

My first choice is Irfanview, because it is easiest to use. Please confirm if [Irfanview can do this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/148005).

If not, please show steps for GIMP. I will download and try to use GIMP.

I never used Photoshop before. I am not photographer, graphic designer, or computer scientist.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Check this answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/148005/157206

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks. i edited my post.

Comment: Irfanview does not have a white balance tool. You can make some colour adjustments with the colour correction feature in the Image menu but it is probably not what you want.

Comment: While I'm not an iOS user, I would be 99% sure that the iOS photos app has the ability to adjust white balance as well if you're happy editing the photos on your phone.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, so do I (not iOS person), but I am 99% sure apple software do not permit you set WB when you take photo.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Not necessarily when you _take_ the photo but you can edit it afterwards. Just seems easier than transferring it off the phone for a simple edit.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, you know very well that when the result is JPG will be better to tune WB before taking a photo.

Comment: There are actually many more adjustable parameters in the iPhone's software than you get in most cheap photo editors - & they're pretty smart too; they require little functional knowledge of photography to use. The internal format will be HEIC rather than jpg [though you can make it save RAW, few people do]. Having said that - I've never known the iPhone to get the WB so far out in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Gimp:

- File > Open
- Colors > Colors balance, and reduce the "intended temperature"
- File > Export to export to a new version or Alt-Shift-S to overwrite current image.

[image]

Don't overdo it.

Next step is to learn to use Gimp to remove that porcelain thing in the back left (photographers learn to mind the background as much as the subject).

Answer (score 2):

In your case you have wrong colour temperature (as it is calculated by phone software). So you can correct it (in some degree) with GIMP following [this manual](https://www.lifewire.com/correct-white-balance-with-gimp-1701672):

> Adjust Color Balance
>
> - Go to Colors > Color Balance to open the Color Balance dialog. ...
> - Select the Shadows radio button.
> - Move the Magenta-Green slider a little to the right. ...
> - In the Midtones and Highlights, adjust the sliders accordingly to get    the most natural color results possible.

To avoid next time such situation you can select software which give you the option to correct those things manualy. Unfortuantely Apple phone software (AFAIK) do not permit you this. So you can take a look on Lightroom mobile which is free and permit you to take RAW photos and later in post you can correct white balance and other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem involves a few adjustments (which are described separately in the other answers).  The underlying principle is to neutralize colors by adding complementary colors: Cyan-Red.  Magenta-Green.  Yellow-Blue.

1. Adjust the color along the **Yellow-Blue** axis.  Also known as **Temperature** or **Warmth**.

   - In GIMP, the tool is found under Colors / Color Temperature.

     - Set Intended Temperature to 3000.  Then adjust up or down.
   - Household bulbs are often 2700-3300K.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Construction), the melting point of tungsten is 3695K.  Bulbs using newer technologies are set around the same color temperature for compatibility with existing bulbs.
2. Adjust colors along the **Magenta-Green** axis.  Also known as **Tint**.

   - In GIMP, look under Colors / Color Balance.

     - Subtract Green (add magenta) in shadows (-10), midtones (-5), and highlights (-20).  Adjust as desired.
   - Shadows and highlights are easier to adjust first because they are usually closer to neutral.  When the temperature of the image more closely matches "white" (the temperature the monitor is set to), color tints are easier to see.
3. Optional: Adjust colors along the **Cyan-Red** axis.

   - This may not be available in basic image editors (eg, phone apps).
   - In GIMP, this is is available under Colors / Color Balance.
   - This isn't strictly necessary because the Yellow-Blue and Magenta-Green axes can be adjusted to match and neutralize the Cyan-Red axis.
4. Optional: Adjust colors with Levels, Curves, or other tools.

   - Same underlying principle of adjusting complementary colors, but may offer finer control.
   - You can also increase contrast (which may be lost in the previous adjustments) with an "S" curve.  This works by darkening shadows and brightening highlights.  This may be available as **Shadows** and **Highlights** (different from the shadow/highlight options in the color balance tool).
5. Optional: Use layer masks to clean up color splotches.

   - This would be needed if you want to clean up the yellow splotches left around the edge of the frame after color correcting your sample photo.  Color splotches are often seen when making extreme edits and in high-ISO, low-light images.
   - Same principle, again.  Neutralize colors by adding the complementary color.  Invert a copy of the image on another layer and paint the mask with a reduced opacity brush (10-30%).  Usually, black = transparent, white = opaque.